# Laravel&Socialite&Nginx : Production Problems with login in services

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, nginx, oauth

I'm working in a Laravel project, i've developed, using Socialite, the Facebook, Twitter & Google Login. In local environment: **no problem, everything is working good**. When I upload to production server, (and change to correct apps configurations, of course), cannot login with any service.

Composer:

- Laravel: 5.2
- Socialite: ^2.0

at config/session.php -> 'domain' is configured with correct domain

client_id & client_secret for all services are ok (as they're working in local env)

When I try to FB login, the result is:

> Client error: `POST https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token`
>   resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"error":{"message":"Missing
>   authorization
>   code","type":"OAuthException","code":1,"fbtrace_id":"HVyIquI4FAD"}}

When I try to Twitter/Google login, the result is:

> InvalidArgumentException in TwitterProvider.php line 15: Invalid
>   request. Missing OAuth verifier.

The callback URI seems to be OK... so I'm very confused.

This is my nginx block config:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

(I tried others... without work)

As I've investigated a lot, seems to be some workaround with nginx or php (cookie config, maybe). Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Did you use a local domain in your app on Facebook/Twitter?

Comment: Yes, when trying in local env. Changed when trying in production env.

Comment: Okay cool, so all the apps made at the social sites are now expecting a request from your proper domain, not a local domain yeah?

Comment: Correct. As I said, the callbacks seems to work (send data as espected to the correct URL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling around for 3 days, losing my mind over this bull of a thing, I finally found out that I had a redirection error in my Nginx sites-enabled configuration.

what I had

```
location / {
    try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.php?\$query_string;
}
```

what I changed it to

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

I hope that I saved someone as blind as me 3 days worth of time.